# Specific html page is not publishing using Google Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

[image: web.app.com & firebaseapp.com page]

This is my web.app.com page after deploying the site using 'firebase deploy'. The firebaseapp.com site is also the same. This is the fully updated version of my site.

[image: Personal .com website]

However, it does not appear in my personal .com website which has been purchased through Google Domains.

I tried updating different pages of my website and the web.app.com, firebaseapp.com, and my personal .com website are being all updated but not this page. I cannot figure out the reason.

I have tried clearing my cache, using a different device, and several different browsers. Nothing has worked.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you confirm that the website is listed in your firebase hosting account as connected or you should try by dis-connecting and then connecting the domain again .also pleas look in to  CDN and DNS If you are using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) or a custom domain, there might be caching or DNS propagation issues. Wait for some time or try accessing the page from a different network to see if the changes reflect.